# How to remove all words in a list from a fixed list of candidates?

Tags: c++, text, vector, stop-words

I'm working on the code which includes comprehensive text preprocessing, including stopwords removal, stemming, boilerplate information removal/substitution (urls, emails, number, money amounts, tags, etc...), building inverted index, LCA, etc. Not exactly surprising - removing stopwords is the bottleneck, the most expensive part of the procedure.

What I have now is pretty simple:

I have around 500 stop-terms stored in static array `static const std::wstring stopwords []`.

Then for each document (`std::vector<wstring>`):

```
for each ( auto term in stopwords)
{
    doc.erase( std::remove( doc.begin(), doc.end(), term), doc.end() );
}
```

Any suggestion how to improve this code's performance?

Comment: Use a `remove_if` with a lambda checking for all words at once

Comment: quantdev, what do you mean by 'checking all words at once'? can you please expand and/or provide example and/or explain why it would be faster? thanks

Comment: Can downvoter explain? It seems to me a legitimate question!

Comment: @user2028058 it means store your stop words in a efficient searchable container, then enumerate the *document* (not the stop words), and for each word in the doc, if it is in the stop words container, remove it. This is what [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) is built to do. Read Gabe's answer for why this will be more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm is n*m, seaching the document multiple times.  Instead you should loop over the words in doc, checking if each is a stopword, and your stopwords should be in a hash table (not a map) so you can do an O(1) check if a given word is a stop word.  That will reduce your time to O(n) where n is the size of the document.

Ex: C++11 provides an unordered set container that you can use for your hash table.

```
std::unordered_set<std::wstring> stopwords; // keep your stop words in here.
```

Once you have that, the trivial solution becomes:

```
doc.erase(std::remove_if(
    doc.begin(),
    doc.end(),
    [](const std::wstring& s){ return stopwords.find(s) != stopwords.end(); }),
    doc.end());
```

Case sensitivity checking not withstanding, (which your original sample did not account for so we didn't here either), this will perform *significantly* better than what you had before, assuming your words has a reasonable hash distribution.

Comment: Excellent! This worked like a charm, improving performance dramatically. Very good advice, thank you guys